# Get Revit space information of a level in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I'm trying to get space information (name, position, level, height) with forge viewer.

I have tried translating the Revit file with the "Generate Master Views" setting. With some Revit models, I can get space information, but some do not. I wonder do I need to do sth with my Revit file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the properties of a selected element on your Revit model?

If so, there are two ways you can go about this.

1. Using the 'Properties' button on the menu tab in the Forge viewer

- You just need to select your element and click the properties button which will display the metadata for the specific selected element.

[image: Forge Viewer Properties button]

2. You can use the **NOP_VIEWER** object on your browser's console.

- You first need to select your element, then on your console type the following:

  NOP_VIEWER.getSelection()

  NOP_VIEWER.getProperties(modelNo, console.log, console.error)

This will display all the metadata of the selected model.

[image: Console Method]